# Launch application on clicking message in Messagelist of Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am using a custom folder in the Messagelist to display when my application gets new message.

Each message contains the title "New information received".

Right now, when the message is clicked it opens a new email compose window.

I have overridden ApplicationMessageFolderListener, but actionPerformed does not seem to be invoked when the message is clicked.

I want to launch my application when the user goes into the Messages application and clicks on my custom message. How do I achieve this?

Target platform: Blackberry 4.0 and above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following code:

```
static class OpenContextMenu extends ApplicationMenuItem {
    public OpenContextMenu( int order ) {
        super( order );
    }

    public Object run( Object context ) {
        if( context instanceof NewMessage ) {
            try {
                NewMessage message = (NewMessage) context;
                if( message.isNew() ) {
                    message.markRead();
                    ApplicationMessageFolderRegistry reg = ApplicationMessageFolderRegistry.getInstance();
                    ApplicationMessageFolder folder = reg.getApplicationFolder( MessageList.INBOX_FOLDER_ID );
                    folder.fireElementUpdated( message, message );
                    //changeIndicator(-1);
                }

                Inbox inbox = message.getInbox();
                Template template = inbox.getTemplate();

                //Launch the mainscreen
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().requestForeground();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Dialog.alert();
            }
        }
        return context;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Name of the menu item";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the detail with the code too, what is NewMessage? And where are we going to write this code or call? How are we going to call it from actionPerformed() function?